# 特定のウィンドウが受信したメッセージをプログラム側から観測できるか

Tags: c#, windows

C#のプログラム上から特定のウィンドウハンドルを取得して、
そのウィンドウがマウス等の操作によってOSから受信したメッセージを
プログラム上で確認したいのですが可能でしょうか。

具体的にはspy++を用いて確認できるメッセージを
プログラム上から取得したいのです。

イメージとしては下記のようなメッセージ情報を取得できることを期待しています。

```
P WM_MOUSEMOVE fwKeys:0000 xPos:504 yPos:414
P WM_MOUSEMOVE fwKeys:0000 xPos:505 yPos:414
P WM_MOUSEMOVE fwKeys:0000 xPos:508 yPos:414
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

C#からは不可能です。

Windowsには[Hook機能](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959(v=vs.85).aspx)が提供されていて、その中でも[WH_GETMESSAGEフック](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959(v=vs.85).aspx#whgetmessagehook)を使用することでウィンドウがメッセージを受信するタイミングをフックすることができます。
ただし、Windows全体はネイティブコードで動作していてこのHook機能においてもネイティブコードが要求されるのに対し、C#言語は.NET Framework上のマネージドコードで動作しているためこのHook機能を利用することができません。
C++言語などを利用して実現することを検討してください。